# How do I stop the browser from jumping to the focused field?

Tags: jquery, focus, overflow, form-fields

I have a form inside a container with overflow:hidden, and I'm changing its className, where each class makes its top-margin to show the proper focused field with focus().

So the jQuery only applies the className. No animation other than webkit is involved.

The problem is that before the animation occurs, the form MOVES inside the container to reveal the hidden field. No value appears changed in the inspector: either top, top-margin, top-padding remain unchanged.

I tried `preventDefaults();` on the focused fields, no success.

Here is a fiddle to show the case.

http://jsfiddle.net/dNk9v/

UPDATE:
I want to make clear that when "tabbing" to the next field, it DOES go there, but the css animation happens on top of it, and the form either jumps no animation or just animates ALONG with the already-happened scrolling/revealing so the expected field ends up outside of the container.

Clicking the legend tag tabs works as expected. I'll try preventing defaults for the keydown events, rather than the focus ones, and I'll keep you updated.

Comment: It seems to work exactly as intended in my Chrome browser ?

Comment: How to you reproduce the problem in the jsFiddle?  I'm also not seeing an issue in Chrome.  Layout doesn't work quite right in Firefox.  Animation doesn't work at all in IE.

Comment: Seems to work in Firefox too.

Comment: I might have not made very clear that the issue happens when you focus a field with TAB key. The legend tag tabs work fine when clicked. The problem is the un-controllable form scrolling to reveal a field when focused with the keyboard (tab key so far. I don't know another way).
It doesn't fail when focused with developer tools. 
It might be the key what triggers it, so the focus is the result, not the cause.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per this post, it seems like a rather complicated problem: https://forum.jquery.com/topic/chrome-bug-or-how-do-i-prevent-a-form-field-to-scroll-the-container-when-focused

I have managed similar issues by manually managing the tabindex attribute of the inputs. This removes the unwanted pseudo-scrolling, but also removes the ability to tab to inputs outside the viewport. If you are willing to live with that, then you can easily add some code to your click handlers to add or remove tabindexes:

```
$(inputEl).attr('tabindex', -1);  // removes tabbing
$(inputEl).attr('tabindex', 1);   // restores tabbing
```

Remove the tab indexes from inputs outside the viewport, and restore them for visible inputs.

Comment: Perfect! It's obvious that I AM creating events for the form clicks anyway, so I don't mind removing the tabs. I actually fixed it by preventing the defaults, but this is the closest to answer my question and leaves the defaults intact :)